# Import csv data into influxdb from python

Tags: influxdb-python

This has almost certainly been asked.

I have `timeseries` data that looks like this in a `.csv` file. The data has no heading, but this is what the different fields are: `date,time,open,high,low,close,volume,0`

```
2017-09-22,21:50:00,131.36,131.415,131.35,131.39,78489,0
2017-09-22,21:55:00,131.39,131.4,131.37,131.38,95322,0
2017-09-22,22:00:00,131.38,131.6,131.31,131.39,1212804,0
```

I am attempting to import this data into `InfluxDB` from `python`. I see in the documentation that you have to create the `json` for it line by line, but I am uncertain how this is done:

This is close, but no cigar. Assume I have the string already split and the datetime-timestamp already in the correct format. When I print the json_body below, I get e.g.,

```
[{'fields': {'Int_value': '1212804', 'Float_value': '131.39'}, 'time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 22, 22, 0), 'measurement': 'quote'}]
```

which doesn't seem right - I seem to be getting only one float value.

**What is the correct JSON for input to InfluxDB?**

```python
import datetime
import random
import time
import os
import csv
from csv import reader
import argparse
from influxdb import client as influxdb


db = influxdb.InfluxDBClient("127.0.0.1", 8086, "", "", "stocks")


def read_data(filename):
    print filename
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()[1:]

    return lines

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = r"jnj.us.csv"
    lines = read_data(filename)
    for rawline in lines:
        line = rawline.split(",")
        d= getPythonDateTimeFromStr(line[0], line[1])
        #EVERYTHING UP TO HERE WORKS. Not sure how to create the json below
        #====================================
        json_body = [
        {
            "measurement": "quote",
            "time": d,
            "fields": {
                "Float_value": line[2],
                "Float_value": line[3],
                "Float_value": line[4],
                "Float_value": line[5],
                "Int_value": line[6]
            }
        }
        ]

        print json_body

        db.write_points(json_body )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duh,

```
"fields": {
            "Float_value": line[2],
            "Float_value": line[3],
            "Float_value": line[4],
            "Float_value": line[5],
            "Int_value": line[6]
 }
```

Should be

```
"fields": {
            "Open": line[2],
            "High": line[3],
            "Low": line[4],
            "Close": line[5],
            "Volume": line[6]
 }
```